# How to get DateTime From Database in Solar Date Fromat (Shamsi Date)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, desktop-application, datetime-format

I am trying to get DataTime from database in Persian Date Fromat,
For this task i made an extinsion method,
and my App Culture is FA-fa, So the DateTime.Now returning Persian Date.

Here is cultureInfo

```cs
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-AF");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-AF");
```

Here is My Code in ViewModel Which makes error:

```cs
long mntRevenue = (long)db.StudentFees
   .Where(f => DateConverter.ToPersianDate(f.Date).Month == DateTime.Now.Month).Sum(s => s.Pay);
```

Error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(s => (DateTime?)s.Date
> .ToPersianDate().Month == DateTime.Now.Month)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'SchoolViewModel.ViewModels.DateConverter.ToPersianDate' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.
> Translation of method 'SchoolViewModel.ViewModels.DateConverter.ToPersianDate' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

My Extinsion Method is:

```cs
public static class DateConverter
{
    #region Static Methods
    public static DateTime ToPersianDate(this DateTime? dt)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dateTime = dt ?? DateTime.Now;
            PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
            string year = persianCalendar.GetYear(dateTime).ToString();
            string month = persianCalendar.GetMonth(dateTime).ToString()
                            .PadLeft(2, '0');
            string day = persianCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(dateTime).ToString()
                            .PadLeft(2, '0');
            string hour = dateTime.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
            string minute = dateTime.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
            string second = dateTime.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
            return DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", year, month, day, hour, minute, second));

        }
        catch { return DateTime.Now; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I want to get date from database and compare it with Current Month and give the compare result to linq expression. The DateTime should be in the Persian Format (Shamsi Date).

Comment: One way is to bring the data into the memory and then apply the filter, but it will have impact on the performance.

Comment: If you can create SQL, then we can find a way which do the same. Otherwise only in memory.

Comment: Use parameters.  Each database has drivers and the driver if you do not use parameters have to guess the variable type and often guess wrong.  You have to convert dates to DateTime if the database stores the dates as strings.  DateTime is a number and format like Shamsi Date doesn't effect the number, it just affects the conversion to string and local time.  Error message suggests you use Raw SQL if necessary.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Database and the the Date Stores in datetime2(7) type. Now How to use parameters or how to use Raw SQL, Currently I am using EF-Core ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who leaves comments, Specially @lets do it.
I found the solution,
I just Remove the ToPersianDate Extinsion Method and Add DateAndPay class,

DateAndPay Class:

```
  public class DateAndPay
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Pay { get; set; }
    }
```

Here it is:

```
PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
int month = persianCalendar.GetMonth(DateTime.Now); 

using AppDbContext db = new();
List<DateAndPay> studentFee = await db.StudentFees.Select(f => new DateAndPay { Date= f.Date,Pay= f.Pay }).ToListAsync();

long mntRevenue = (long)studentFee.Where(f => persianCalendar.GetMonth(f.Date) == month).Sum(f=> f.Pay);
```